# Different colors in columns, Padas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors

I have Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"fuel":["gas","gas","diesel","diesel","gas","diesel"]})
```

And I used code to make a bar plot:

```
ax1 = data.fuel.value_counts().plot('bar')
ax1.set(xlabel = 'Fuel Type', ylabel='Frequency of fuel type')
```

Nevertheless, I have both column in one colo (blue). What should I do to have different colors of columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can set color parameters in plot().

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"fuel":["gas","gas","diesel","diesel","gas","diesel"]})

data.fuel.value_counts().plot('bar', color=['black', 'red'])
ax1.set(xlabel = 'Fuel Type', ylabel='Frequency of fuel type')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of random colors by the size of unique values of `data.fuel` and pass it to option `color` of `plot`

```
colors = [np.random.uniform(size=3) for _ in  range(data.fuel.nunique())]
ax1 = data.fuel.value_counts().plot('bar', color=colors)
ax1.set(xlabel = 'Fuel Type', ylabel='Frequency of fuel type')
```